# How to load a json 3.1 format model in three.js

Tags: 3d, three.js

1. Is that still possible to load 3.1 json format models in tree.js of current verion (r73 as of now).
2. If no what is that last version supporting it?

The problem I'm having is that I'm using http://oos.moxiecode.com/js_webgl/md5_converter/ to convert the models in runtime from md5 to json . But this tool generates json format 3.1. Which seems like I couldn't load using the lastest three.js